# Are cheap electric helicopters feasible to produce?

Tags: technology, aircraft, manufacturing

I am designing a human society that exists in the near future. After the development of mass-produced, relatively cheap lithium-sulfur batteries (superior energy density to lithium-ion), electric vehicles- particularly aircraft- become much easier to engineer, as batteries are not nearly as heavy and can carry a longer charge.

As the society exists in extremely difficult terrain, the military funds the development of low-cost, battery-powered helicopters. These two- or four-seater helicopters have decent range (350 miles or so), and are small, light, and (relatively) simple to operate and maintain, and cost less than (the modern equivalent of) $70,000 apiece. They are primarily used as a cheap and easy method of transportation or for reconnaissance, being too small for heavy weapons. They are quite common and (ideally) intuitive to fly, even to one with minimal flight experience, so much so that a streamlined mainstream model becomes quite popular with civilians living in undeveloped areas.

[This article](https://www.waaytv.com/news/six-rotors-200mph-this-electric-helicopter-may-be-the-future-of-transportation/article_746d2500-b3b4-509f-8692-ee2581735fee.html#:%7E:text=With%20a%20distance%20of%20up,can%20help%20relieve%20urban%20congestion.) makes it seem like electric helicopters are potentially feasible, even with lithium-ion batteries. However, my understanding of helicopters is that they are not easy to fly and are usually quite expensive due to complex mechanics. [This helicopter](https://aerocorner.com/aircraft/robinson-r44/), which seems similar to what I'm shooting for, costs over six times what I'd like mine to.

Are cheap, dime-a-dozen electric helicopters possible to manufacture?

Comment: Several companies are developing electric quad-copter-like person-carrying flying machines, and at least a couple are already on the market (albeit not cheap).  A conventional rotor helicopter is more efficient, albeit less amenable to computer control (though a quad-copter is literally impossible for human reflexes to stabilize without computer assistance).

Comment: Unrelated but an interesting side note: zip lines and other "Tyrolean Traverses" have been in used for *literally* thousands of years in very difficult terrain. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_line I would expect this (along with elevators) to be common for citizenry in the area, but it would pose a problem for helicopters. If the blades hit a line, it's bad news for everyone involved. Not to mention it's much cheaper to string a steel cable for any standing infrastructure.

Comment: Gyrocopters....

Comment: Why go for manned helicopters in the first place? Current trend is going all in into drone warfare. You can use smaller quadrocopters, as you don't need to carry extra 300+ kg for the crew (which is a waste of both weight as well as space). Or you replace the saved weight by adding more sensors/weapons. And even ignoring all those pros of using unmanned drones, probably the most important perk is that your loses are way more acceptable (both for your military, and for your civilians): hardware is cheaper than people.

Comment: Helicopters mostly go with a constant rpm, then have a collective pitch to make your copter go up and down, and an overlayed pitch that controls the direction. This means a lot of highly stressed mechanical linkages, none of which will go away by taking the whole thing electric. Drones do variable rpm and fixed pitch, essentially going for the 'we'll fix it in software' approach. The bladelength makes them inherently inefficient, though. Could your society live with a helicopter with normal size main rotor for efficiency, but fixed pitch of the blades, and extra-prop-pods for maneuvering?

Comment: @bukwyrm They could live with fixed-pitch; this vehicle is purely designed for cheapness/simplicity above all else. I was thinking of taking a transverse approach with two fixed-pitch rotors (like in Avatar), but I’m not sure that’s the same since transverse rotors are also highly complex.

Comment: @Negdo the helicopters are designed for moving people, basically like a flying Jeep. A drone could work as long as it can still carry 2-4 people, but I assumed if people would be in the thing anyway they could drive it too.

Comment: Define "near future". Tomorrow, no. Next year, doubt it. 100 years from now, maybe.

Comment: @MarkPrice My point is that human soldiers are more and more obsolete with each passing decade. Why would you transport troops if drones can do soldiers' job? Just look at the current Ukraine-Russian war. When a drone notice your position, you are practiaclly dead: either the drone explode, or send your location to a remote artilery position. And in this war both sides use outdated hardware...

Comment: Even lithium-sulfur batteries won't be as amazing as most people think.  Sure, they're better, but hydrocarbon energy storage is still roughly 50 times as dense.  Factor in that electric motors are more efficient than combustion motors and that brings it down to *only* 25X as dense. And you still have to get the electricity to charge the batteries from *somewhere* anyway.  Not that electric passenger aircraft couldn't happen, but I think it would take something better than lithium-sulfur to push the breakover point of the weight/power/range scale far enough in favor of electric.

Answer (score 15):

**Microlite Aircraft**

[image]

Microlite aircrafts are the sort of things that Father and Son teams build and repair in their garage on weekends and then fly over the farmsteads of Cornwall. Weather permitting of course.

Microlites are not helicopters. But it does not seem important for your question that the cheap small electric aircraft is a helicopter. Certainly a fixed wing machine is easier to fly than a spinner.

The microlite uses gasoline for fuel and weighs about 100kg. For reference that's about 0.85 Dwayne Johnsons. [In the US a microlite can have a fuel tank at most 20kg big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation). The battery is about one quarter as weight-efficient as the fuel. Wikipedia says the batteries have a theoretical efficiency of about 2500 Wh/kg compared to about 12,000 for gasoline. If you replace one of the two passengers with an 80kg battey you might get the same amount of power in a one-passenger electric aircraft as a two-seater gasoline aircraft.

Comment: Worth noting that in the USA, a Part 103 Ultralight (equivalent to your microlight category) is also limited to a single seat and has a level flight top speed limit.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Sure, but those are regulatory limits, not engineering ones. It's not that you couldn't build an ultralight with two seats and a high top speed, but they'd make you get a pilot's license to fly it.

Comment: And in the USA, they call that a "light sport" airplane, or whatever name that class wound up with -- the license has restrictions on aircraft weight and passenger carrying, as a tradeoff for requiring a fraction of the instruction to qualify.

Comment: @ZeissIkon It seems some two seaters are a bit heavier than Dwayne. But [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB_Microlight_BB-two_seater) at least seems to weigh only 0.77 Dwaynes and carry two people.

Comment: "the society exists in extremely difficult terrain" – it might be difficult to have runways long enough for a non-VTOL air vehicle.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann [Some of these things can take off an land in a few dozen metres.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siKsFe-11oc)

Comment: Microlite/kit helicopters also [exist](https://www.theautopian.com/you-can-buy-a-tiny-helicopter-that-costs-just-35000-and-could-fit-in-some-garages/#:~:text=The%20closest%20thing%20to%20it,for%20a%20factory%2Dbuilt%20model.). They are relatively safe due to the rotor drag in case of critical failures, with legislative support (safety) features can be minimised for a truly accessible mode of transportation. Foot cranking can extend the range for the truly cost-conscious.

Comment: @user3819867  What is rotor drag? Are these little copters safer than normal helicopters? I am told the big ones things are a nightmare to fly.

Comment: @user3819867 I would be curious about the weight issue for replacing the engine with a battery. The little copter weight a touch over 1 DJ and only holds one person. There is not another personsworth of weight to replace with a big battery.

Comment: From the link, it looks like the ultralight copters are indeed in that price range. The cheapest 1-seater was listed as $35k.

Comment: For an even smaller option, powered hang gliders and paramotors are also things. Weight tends to be around a semidwayne, and easily fits into/onto a car if needed. Takeoff distances can be very short indeed.

Comment: Worth noting that you also have to compare electric motor efficiency with ICE, which means the battery performs better than energy density comparison alone would indicate.  Still tricky, but any of those class of aircraft are dicey.

Comment: @jdunlop Good point. We should compare the weight of the battery to the weight of the fuel + engine itself.

Comment: @Graham Yeah a good hang glider can weigh less than Simone Johnson.

Comment: @Daron Rotor drag: I meant autorotation. With helicopters transferring height to speed goes more smoothly than with planes, to the extent that depending on instructor autorotation landing can be part of the training. Weight: OP started with a battery breakthrough with higher density plus government support, so the weight can be "streamlined" (i.e. janky unsafe vehicles). For a proper answer I would need to pick parts.

Answer (score 12):

### No

Your battery technology only does one thing to current helicopter designs: it replaces the motor and fuel tank of today's helicopters. All other aspects of the helicopter remain the same and cost the same.<sup>1</sup>

We can [look at what helicopter engines cost today](https://www.pwc.ca/en/products-and-services/services/sales-rentals-and-exchanges/engine-sales#available-engines) and see that they're about \$375,000. The helicopter you link to in your post has a price tag of about \$450,000. That means *everything else* costs \$75,000, which is already more than the cost you want.

The electric motor and batteries just add to that cost. And no matter how inexpensive the batteries are, the cost of the motor will always be substantial.

However, how far into the future are we looking? Today's technology becomes cheaper over time, so it's not impossible, *eventually.*

But, today... no. You'll be hard pressed to get the helicopters into the \$150k-\$250k price range.

***But does any of that matter?***

Today people look forward to electric vehicles with a lot of hope. So much that they don't even bother to look behind the curtain of their local electric car charging station and see the diesel generators lurking there.

In short, I believe people will find your idea *plausible,* and therefore suspend their disbelief to continue with the story.

I don't think it's worth asking whether or not what you're trying to do "can" be achieved at the cost you want. Who cares? I love the idea and hope you'll stop worrying about whether or not it's possible to really build one right now and move on with your story.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *This isn't entirely true. The combustion engine and fuel tank will be heavier and take more space than the electric version will. That means the helicopter as a whole can be built smaller and more cheaply vs. its combustion counterpart while carrying the same load. However, I do not believe that will reduce the price enough to materially change my answer.*</sub>

Comment: Economies of scale can also drive down the cost.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Economy of scale doesn't drive down the cost. Demand drives increased production and then economy of scale brings lower prices. But in the long run, I think that part of the question is an unnecessary debate. It wouldn't be a challenge to come up with a series of invented events that result in (e.g.) economy of scale. That's just window dressing for a story where the OP decides what the cost for his/her helicopters are.

Comment: On the controls issue - would be interesting to see how practical it would be to replace the very-difficult-to-master cyclic+collective+pedals+throttle combination with simplified computer-assisted controls.  (P23-29 of Chickenhawk by Robert Mason gives a great description of how hard they are to learn.)  Strongly suspect that computer assistance for ease of learning would reduce the pilot's options in some situations.  Agree with everything re production costs +1

Comment: Electric motors will do away with a huge amount of highly-stressed mechanical stuff in a helicopter. Direct drive to the rotors and computer control of motor speeds. As we see with quad-copter drones.  However, weight and range are a fundamental problem for batteries. Enter large numbers of fast-charge helipads?

Comment: You can get a single seat gasoline "helicopter" for ~35.000€: The [SCH-2A](https://mirocopter.com/en_US/), though it does come with a few tradeoffs... Wind in your hair is one of them.

Comment: @predi But [those things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu9PRXJh65o) can only fly three foot off the ground.

Comment: @nigel222 Quadcopters trade a LOT of efficiency and control complexity for efficiency mechanical simplicity. Control complexity might be only be an engineering issue since the quadcopter being so difficult to fly *requires* an auto-pilot whereas it is optional on a single-rotor heli ultimately makes quadcopters require less skill. However, efficiency is much more difficult. Quadcopters compound aerodynamic inefficiency on top of battery ineffectiveness for the sake of mechanical simplicity.

Comment: @DKNguyen So a single direct-drive rotor on top and a tail rotor? Still a lot simpler than a mechanical transmission. Are the big two-rotor choppers also  inefficient? (Chinook etc.)

Comment: @nigel222 Chinooks would be less efficient than a helicopter with a single *massive* rotor. But two rotors were chosen due to technological constraints and payload form-factor reasons. Going electric single-rotor doesn't do away with the mechanically complex swash plate and I suspect you still need a gearbox anyways since electric motors are likely to turn too fast for a helicopter rotor. They certainly do for model sizes. It might be a simpler gearbox though.

Comment: @predi While true, your observation fails to meet the OP's stated expectations. We're not allowed to get the price down by abdicating his requirements.

Comment: @nigel222 I'm afraid that you're oversimplifying too much. Even existing electric cars have transmissions. A direct-drive motor that can handle the entire sweep of torque and speed is bulky and inefficient. You're saving transmission complexity, but you're adding weight and draining power (large motors cost more to operate at lower speed/torque values). You're also stuck with mounting the motor in rlation to the rotors in only one way. There are reasons why transmissions are used. Gears are your friends.

Comment: "the cost of the motor will always be substantial." This is just plain wrong. Electric motors cost NOTHING when compared to combustion engines. And that is as of right now, where high-power gas engines have had way more engineering poured into them

Comment: @JBH they do have transmissions, but only single-speed transmissions. And with helicopters this will be even more viable than in cars because 99% of run time will be within a slim range of power

Comment: @Hobbamok "...when compared to..." What does that have to do with it? Are we having a political debate? The cost of an electric motor is not zero, therefore the number remaining after removing the combustion motor must be increased by the cost of the electric motor. Do you have an actual problem? Or are you just blindly advocating for electric motors, which has nothing to do with the question or my answer?

Comment: @Hobbamok Oh good grief. *They have whatever transmissions are needed for the appropriate distribution of energy for the purpose of the drive train.* I'm an engineer kiddo. Electric motors aren't magic. Why did my Toyota Prius have a multi-gear transmission connected to the electric motor? Not surprisingly, because electric motors aren't magic.

Comment: @JBH you're an engineer of mistaking anecdotes for fact. I can google. https://www.kia.com/dm/discover-kia/ask/do-electric-cars-have-transmissions.html Some EVs might have multi-gear transmissions, but that is a dying trend from a time when electric engines for cars weren't up to spec.  Nobody is talking about magic or whatever, you are delusional

Comment: Oh god Grief. @JBH using my magical  skills (googling) i figured out why your Prius has a gearbox: BECAUSE IT IS A HYBRID AND THE COMBUSTION PART NEEDS ONE ANYWAY. https://getjerry.com/questions/does-prius-make-an-all-electric-car . And being an engineer you'll easily understand that IF YOU ALREADY HAVE A GEARBOX you might as well use it for the electric part as well so you can use cheaper Electric engines. Soo, either you were  bullshitting me or are the worst engineer I know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140342/discussion-between-hobbamok-and-jbh).

Answer (score 7):

**Drones/Quadcopters not Helicopters**

[image: H]

They are smaller and more intuitive to fly. They can be partially or fully automated. They have fewer moving parts making them easier to maintain.

A 3d carbon fibre body could be printed where the cost could be reduced to that point.

If you look at electric cars, you have four electric motors, battery system, electronic control system, battery and a carbon fibre body all around that price range. If today's batteries were smaller and motors were more efficient, you could mass produce quadcopters exactly the same way.

Comment: Are you sure you use the right terminology here? "Drone" means it's somewhat autonomous, not that it has four propellers (that would be "quadcopter").

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann a drone is an unpiloted vehicle of any type. A "quadcopter" is one type of vehicle. One can have piloted and unpiloted quadcopters. An unpiloted quadcopter is appropriated described as a drone. However, more to the point, Thorne... A drone removes the pilot's weight and carbon fiber tech can be applied to any vehicle. How does your post answer the OP's question(s)?

Comment: A quadcopter/drone is mechanically far simpler than a helicopter. It's can be semi/fully automated making it easy to fly. Has less moving parts so is easier to maintain.

Comment: you may want to look at something like the eVTOL, many are essentially a piloted  electric quadcopter. several are already in use. drone is just confusing terminology. with a little fleshing out this could be a great answer.

Comment: @Thorne and they can't autorotate, so any failure in one of the four motors would lead to a crash. This is not a huge problem with today's small hobby drones only carrying a camera, but imagine millions of them over a city in the rush hour, carrying people.

Comment: Hexacopters are tolerant of one or two motor failures.  Octacopters are even more failure tolerant.

Comment: Some companies have been developing [parachutes for helicopters](https://zefhir.eu/2018/09/27/a-big-step-forward-in-the-history-of-flight-safety/) (Not affiliated, just an example). I imagine it would be easier in a quadcopter as you wouldn't need to mount it above the rotor, so that could be another safety feature.

Comment: @vsz: Is the lack of auto-rotate a physical limitation of the concept, or just a control limitation because it's not worth developing finer (more complex) controls on today's cheap drones? The former would be a dead-end, the latter would be solvable.

Comment: @B-K parachutes need a considerable height in order to function properly. Autorotation also needs some height, but much less. And as the blades of the drones act more like propellers than wings, it seems the lack of autorotation are a physical limitation. I've never seen autorotation even as a proof of concept on small compact blades.

Comment: Few if any electric cars have four motors -- the top-end version of the Tesla Model S has only three (and still out-accelerates anything not expressly built as a drag racer).  Very high power electric motors are expensive, batteries with high output and charge rates are expensive even compared to same chemistry and capacity with lower charge/discharge limits.  When a single-motor electric with half the range costs twice as much as my daily commuter vehicle did seven years ago, I don't hold much hope for electric power making helicopters affordable, never mind if they're practical.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Quadcopter rotors have multiple smaller rotors so they don't have the inertia to autorotate, and even if they did, the other difference is that each rotor only has one degree of freedom: rotating. If you lose power to all your rotors you aren't going to be able to control any autorotation that may or may not happen, and if you have power to all your rotors to control the autorotation that means you can just fly. Auto-rotating for a single failed rotor, if you even have enough rotor RPM, is going to be *very* dangerous.

Comment: Forget energy management by quickly descending to convert your gravitational potential into energy to spool up RPM in the rotor and then spending it all in a last minute flare for a soft landing. The failed rotor, which already has low inertia, and you that you have zero control over, will completely dictate your descent to the ground. All you can do is pray it doesn't stop freewheeling until you hit the ground and adjust the surviving rotors to match the failed rotor so you don't flip on the way down. Attempting spool up or flare the failed rotor with surviving rotors will just cause a flip.

Answer (score 6):

Electric helicopters won't be cheap any time soon, even with lithium-sulfur battery technology.

We've been able to build practical electric cars (at least for city use) for more than a century, but the ones with enough range and performance to get out of a city or travel between cities currently cost about twice what an economy model gasoline powered car of similar specs (passenger/load capacity, acceleration, and range) does -- and as technology is continually added, even gasoline powered cars are headed for price ranges where they won't be universally affordable.

Given the much higher minimum power requirement for a helicopter to remain aloft vs. a car traveling on a highway, plus the need to lift a heavy battery, endurance and performance will tend to be poor compared to fuel powered aircraft.  Current quad-copter type electric aircraft have a flight duration of less than an hour (much less, in some cases).  A conventional rotor layout would help (fixed wing even more so), but even an electric version of a Cessna 152 isn't yet a practical reality.

Comment: Bad analysis. Today 50% of EV costs are due to it being electric, with 25% on just the battery cell alone. https://www.statista.com/statistics/940722/bev-manufacturing-cost-by-type/ This is a price that is going to drop immensely. Same for engine and engine-electronics. These are parts with a ridiculous fraction of the engineering that combustion engines have enjoyed. Their prices (or price per performance) is going to drop rapidly as the field develops. OP is not talking about having it in 2024, your analysis is

Comment: @Hobbamok Or maybe battery prices won't drop as predicted.  I don't see combustion engines costing a lot less (in real money) than they did in, say, 1970, in fact they cost more -- they also burn less fuel and pollute less, but they certainly don't cost the end user less, and the rest of the car has virtually doubled in cost in real money over that time.

Comment: 1970s combustion engines are the Nokia 3110's  of combustion engines. You are saying that phones got more expensive because an Iphone 16 costs more than your Nokia 3110. They are barely in the same class.  And you don't buy "one battery in this car please" but you combine a ton of cells together, something that engines can't do. And guess what cell prices per kwh are doing quite rapidly. Falling. And that is without OPs given Lithium-Sulphur, which will do to battery prices what gasoline engines did to combustion engines  in general (= wood or coal fired steam engines) when it came around.

Comment: But sure, maaaaaybe prices don't drop for some reason. But OP isn't asking for a future analysis for the purpose of investing or so. They asked for general fictional feasability, which means we can assume good or neutral conditions. And also: no, the rest of the car has NOT doubled in cost. There is just more stuff in a car nowadays.  Stop looking at Iphone16's, stop looking at BMWs latest car . We (me & OP) are talking about Lada Nivas here. And their prices are historically declining significantly.

Answer (score 4):

**Flocking drones.**

[image: drone flock lifts truck]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkysTzikBBU

Pretty sweet ad!

Let us consider small cheap drones, because I too am small and cheap.  Let us consider a 100 USD dollar civilian drone that can lift 0.5 kg.  I weigh 100 kg in the buff.  It will thus take 200 drones to lift me.  That is 20,000 worth of drone.  We will add another 100 drones because my drone harness is heavy (that is real gold) and I will want to bring snacks.  30,000.  That is half of what you ask for a helicopter in (inflated future dollars!) and the flocking drones are better.

1. Redundant: if one malfunctions you don't fall from the sky.
2. Redundant: if some are in the shop you can deploy your spares and keep on flying.
3. Flexible - I might send only part of my fleet to carry my cat from place to place, or add some drones for hire when the flock carries me home from the barbeque place.
4. Cheap.  We started with cheap, and small.

The trick here is the flocking software.  Flocking drones are not new or futuristic.

[image: drone swarm at olympics]

https://dronebelow.com/2018/02/10/record-breaking-intel-drone-swarm-lights-pyeongchang-olympic-winter-games-2018/

Answer (score 2):

The main reason helicopters are expensive is safety standards (redundant systems, parts that don't have mechanical failures, all kinds of sensors for avoiding things like mid-air collisions, communication and navigation systems, etc).

If you don't mind catching on fire before plummeting to your death you could probably produce small helicopters for less than $10000.

For a fictional military, "cheap and unsafe" helicopters is very plausible (why spend $$ when you're probably going to be shot down anyway?).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any issues with the lithium sulfur batteries (powerful batteries can be difficult to develop and produce, but the question seems to indicate this is a non-issue in your world), I don't see why not. A sophisticated computer system on your helicopters can make flying accessible to everyone, or even fully automatic. We have drones, and what's a helicopter if not a really big drone?

Adding an advanced computer system, however, is going to drive the price up. Luckily, however, you stated that the military funds the development of these helicopters. Government subsidies can help keep the price down (if they want everyone to use these helicopters, they'll be eager to promote their usage).

I'm sure there are other issues which make these helicopters less viable in our world, but none of them are major enough that you can't hand-wave them away with "computers" or "money" or something along those lines.

Comment: I expect that there's more than enough raw compute power in any gamer's PC. Drones can be controlled by a Raspberry Pi! The issue is software. It has a high development cost but zero reproduction cost. So once it's been developed, the price can progressively fall. Initially, it will be sold at high cost to the highest bidder (the military). Once they have bought all they want, the price will be dropped to catch other markets. And then, the competition will arrive and the price will be driven right down.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

More specifically, a low-performing version could become substantially cheaper than today's helicopters or today's electric cars. (A low-performing, much cheaper version of electric cars should also be possible.)

The technology — and hence the complexity — of electric transportation is much simpler than with combustion engines. You can get an idea if you look at the development of model drones; 40 years ago, they were basically James Bond issue, expensive cutting-edge technology unaffordable for the general public. Today you find them in blister packaging hanging by the supermarket cash register, and they run until you crash them without any maintenance. Batteries, circuits, electric motors and the plastic body are that simple and cheap.

There is, however, a floor to the price of large items simply because of the amount of energy and material needed to produce them; an electric car will always cost more than an electric bike. But with cheap batteries there is no reason why a "[google bubble car](https://www.fastcompany.com/3031146/googles-self-driving-car-is-real-and-it-looks-like-a-tiny-bubble-car)" or a corresponding "bubble quadcopter" should be much more expensive than half a ton of plastic, 200 kg of Lithium and a kilometer of copper wire. Because of the mechanical and power limitations you won't be able to perform aerial acrobatics or fly races with it, but they'll get you from A to B in a rather boring fashion, just like a google bubble car.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are mass produced, the best option is quad copters or some type of ring around the propellers otherwise there would be a high risk flying on of these as you are not constantly looking up when flying. One wing broken means that you have to get out. There is also a potential danger when the helicopter falls to the ground.